# Keep Using Microsoft Reader After It Has Been Discontinued

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app, pdf-reader, windows-store

As of today (16/02/2018) Microsoft has apparently discontinued the [Microsoft Reader](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/reader/9wzdncrfhwg5) app. Per [this article](https://www.windowslatest.com/2017/11/21/microsoft-to-discontinue-its-pdf-reader-app-in-february-2018/)

> After updating to the latest version of the Reader App, users will be getting a notification when launching the application informing them about the app being discontinued or pulled in February 2018.
>
> The app will not be usable beyond the above mentioned date and the users are hence advised to use the Microsoft Edge Browser for reading PDF, Windows XPS Viewer for XPS and Windows Photos for TIFF files.

In my opinion it is the best PDF Reader out there (For Double Click on PDF -> Just load it as fast as possible without any bells and whistles).

My question is whether there is a way to keep it running by overriding whatever is going on that prevents it from running?

In addition, any way to keep its installation to make it run on future installation of Windows I will have just like you can keep APK in Andorid?

Comment: Another source for the announcement/removal: https://www.onmsft.com/news/microsoft-ending-support-for-its-windows-8-10-reader-app

Comment: Not that this has anything directly to do with Microsoft Reader, but if you choose to try another PDF reader, for simplicity, speed and no bells/whistles/just double click to open, [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) deserves a hard look.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, I'm using Sumatra PDF for years ([Sumatra PDF Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/sumatra_pdf_portable)). Yet still as my default PDF reader I prefer MS Reader. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

In the update from 15th January 2018 Microsoft made the app unusable. It is only a stub to show to open PDFs om Edge.

To go back to a working version, [disable the automatic update of store apps](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6664-turn-off-automatic-updates-apps-windows-10-store.html) in the Microsoft Store settings as shown in the picture:

[image]

Uninstall the reader app on your device, now activate the [option to sideload appx file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10)

- Open Settings.
- Click `Update & Security` > `For developers`.
- On Use *developer* features, select **Sideload apps**.

Now download the `Microsoft.Reader_2017.209.2029.4759_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.AppxBundle` from one of the mirrors [1](https://mega.nz/#!F8AggKLT!PbWyAIUdeUmorTm6FVTPNflom39P4agHd5yzagTg6JI)|[2](https://archive.org/details/Microsoft.Reader2017.209.2029.4759Neutral8wekyb3d8bbwe) (last version that I have, I'm not sure if this is last version before the update)

and make a double click on it to install it via the [App Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/app-installer/9nblggh4nns1).

Now don't update the Reader app any longer in Microsoft store (but update the other apps on your own to get improvements for all other apps) to keep this working version of the Reader app.

Comment: Not only is this illegal, this is a security risk to turn off automatic updates of store apps.

Comment: @AllenHoward troll somewhere else. You can still manually update other apps. *facepalm *

Comment: Sure you can, but in terms of best practice security this is a security risk.  Why does Microsoft force updates on Windows 10?  Because people don't update manually.

Comment: eh, you're a trusted user we're familiar with but sticking a random file on dropbox kind of means the person downloading it needs to trust you, and

Comment: @JourneymanGeek open properties of the appx and look at the signature tab ‍♂️

Comment: and that your answer relies on you, MS not breaking another day and dropbox. If someone flags this some day, as the link not working or the software not working... eh. for now though, I guess it'll work.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Security signatures checked out. Btw I did not need to enable sideloading for this to install. I'm guessing since it was signed by Microsoft, Windows 10 20H2 automatically took it in.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no legitimate way to continue using the application.  Microsoft has always said that any of the "Modern"/Universal apps could disappear from the app store at any time.

Windows is also tricky in side-loading apps, although it is possible with developer options.  That being said, since this is a Microsoft application, I doubt you'd be able to find the package for it anywhere to install it.

Comment: I still had an old package and posted it

Comment: @magicandre1981, be careful with that-- you are now illegally distributing Microsoft applications/code.

Comment: I really don't see why they do it like that. Stop adding features, but why make the application unusable. I thought they would do what they did with Pain.

Comment: They want everyone to use Edge, that's why.  It's unfortunate, but Microsoft does what Microsoft wants to do.  Also, any known security vulnerabilities won't be patched, so that's an issue, as well.

Comment: @Royi - They determined work required to keep the program updated (i.e. security updates) wasn't worth the responsibility of keeping it functional.  Same reasons TrueCrypt developers took the last version that could encrypt down, and only provided a version, that could decrypt.

Comment: I'm not against the idea not offering it anymore. I'm against their action - disable it. For instance, If I use Windows Vista, which is not yet supported, they don't, suddenly, make it stop booting (Or not letting it connect the internet), right?