# Microsoft Reader App Keeps Crashing

Tags: windows-10, crash, pdf-reader, windows-10-v1809, uwp

This question [has been asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/1295602/keep-using-microsoft-reader-after-it-has-been-discontinued), but I'm asking again because it has been a while since that one was asked.

I'm aware that the Reader app has been discontinued, and that it is possible to keep using it by having the .appx file on hand. That worked perfectly some time ago, but a while ago I had my disk formatted and now I have to reinstall it. The installation failed first time, saying it needed VCLibs, so I downloaded and installed what it asked for, and it installed fine after that. However, it keeps crashing when I try to open a file. I tried both opening a file and opening the app, both to no avail. I don't see any error messages at all, the app simply opened for a while showing the splash screen, and then closed itself.

What can I do to get it to work again? I'm running Windows 10 Pro Build 1809. Currently updating to Windows 10 Pro Build 1909.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That app was discontinued over a year ago, and cannot be brought back in a new system (new or newly installed). So you need to find a different app or application for this purpose.

Comment: @John Yes I'm aware it was discontinued, but it was still possible to use it. Simply install the .appx file. It worked for a while, as noted in the older question I linked, and now I'm looking for ways I can keep using it.

Comment: Try running app troubleshooter  ; i think issue is due to upgrades